# Data loss when using the service-based database?

Tags: c#, database

I use the command "insert into" to add a record to the database, but when I run the application, the data I added does not exist, ie the database is empty.

I've closed the connection, but no data is stored, what can I do?

Code:

```
SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(global::app.Properties.Settings.Default.DatabaseConnectionString); 
try 
{ 
    string  sql = "INSERT INTO tbl (field) VALUES ('"+ lblText.Text + "');";  
    SqlCommand sqlc = new SqlCommand(sql, cn); 
    cn.Open(); 
    sqlc.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
} catch (Exception ex) { } finally { cn.Close(); }
```

Comment: put breakpoint, debug it, check the log, make sure pointing to correct and yeah, show your code!

Comment: SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(global::app.Properties.Settings.Default.DatabaseConnectionString);
            try
            {
                string sql = "INSERT INTO tbl (field) VALUES ('"+ lblText.Text + "');";
                SqlCommand sqlc = new SqlCommand(sql, cn);
                cn.Open();
                sqlc.ExecuteNonQuery();

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
             
            }
            finally
            {
                cn.Close();
            }

Comment: Are you overwriting the .mdf each time you run? Normally a lone .mdf file is a bad idea anyway, you should rely on a serious database connecting to the engine and creating the DB there.

Comment: You wrapped your code with try..catch so it silently swallows all errors. Remove the try..catch or debug your code when it gets to the `catch` line to see what the error was.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ofer Zelig is correct that you should not be ignoring exceptions, so the first thing to do is confirm that an exception is not being thrown.  If it is then address that specifically.

Assuming there's no exception, Alejandro is correct that you are quite possibly overwriting the database every time.  That is the default behaviour.

He is, however, wrong about using an MDF data file in your app.  There's nothing wrong with doing so as long as it's not a multi-client application.  The database is still attached to a SQL Server instance at run time.

When you add a service-based database to your project, the MDF file becomes a source file.  Just like all source files, the running application knows nothing about it.  When you build, that MDF file is copied into the output folder along with the EXE.  It's that copy that you connect to at run time and that copy that you make changes to.  By default, each time you build a new copy is created, thus overwriting any changes you made to the old copy.

Select your data file in the Solution Explorer and open the Properties window.  Change the 'Copy to output directory' property to "Copy if newer" from the default "Copy always".  Now, a new copy will only be created if you have actually changed the source file, e.g. changed the schema.  That means that any changes you make during one run will remain in the database the next time you run, even if the project gets built in between.  If you want to look for the data in the database, just make sure that you look in the copy in the output folder and not the source in the project folder.

Comment: I realized my problem, thank you very much

Comment: thanks Ofer Zelig and Alejandro